# Is there a connected compact manifold $M$ of dimension 4 such that $\pi_1 (M) = \mathbb{Z} * (\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Is there a connected compact manifold $M$ of dimension 4 such that $\pi_1 (M) = \mathbb{Z} * (\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3)$? I had this question in a test yesterday. I think that the answer is no, because of the $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (it in general makes things not locally euclidean), however I do not know how to prove it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have any finitely generated group as the fundamental group of a compact four manifold.

For your example, take a lens space in 3d, cross it with a circle, then take a 3-sphere crossed with a circle, then attach the two spaces by connected sum.

Comment: Could prove or give me a reference for the statement "You can have any finitely generated group as a fundamental group of a compact four manifold."  ?

Comment: See this MO question:http://mathoverflow.net/q/30238/27933

Comment: The reason is essentially that generators are single dimensional and relators are two dimensional, and two-dimensional things fit nicely into 5-dimensional space. Smoothing it into a manifold makes it 4-d.